# Using the estimated robot pose from robot_pose_ekf with amcl

Tags: navigation, odom-combined, robot-pose-ekf, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) to fuse data from Wheel encoders and IMU to estimate the 3D pose of the robot. Then, I am using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) to take care of odometry drift and finally the [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) package does the navigation. I am generating the odom message of the type `nav_msgs/Odometry` from the wheel encoders which is used by the [base_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=indigo). I know robot_pose_ekf provides odom_combined to base_link transformation which is used by amcl.
My question is once robot_pose_ekf fuses the data from wheel encoders and IMU and generates the estimated 3D pose of the robot of the type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` on the topic `robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined`, how and where is this output used in the navigation package as a whole (move_base or amcl)?

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208197/using-the-estimated-robot-pose-from-robot_pose_ekf-with-amcl/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

amcl dont use `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`  message. Its nothing but `tf` from `odom_combined -> base_link` combined with covariance.  As you mentioned amcl get the same pose from tf and amcl doesnt need pose covariance.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-01**:
Thanks! So, basically the estimated robot pose from robot_pose_ekf is not used anywhere, its just the transformation between odom_combined and base link (which contains all the relevant information) which is used by amcl, right?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2015-05-01**:
yes , transformation is nothing but estimate pose from ekf without covariance info.

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-05-01**:
Ok..Thanks!

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-11-07**:
"the estimated robot pose from robot_pose_ekf is not used anywhere," is that right ??
so why we use it?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-11-07**:
No, covariance information is not used in amcl.

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-11-07**:
ok so i need to do robot_pose_ekf for encoders and IMU, and AMCL would use it instead of tf_diff ?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-11-08**:
amcl needs odometry, most of the time odometry is from encoder and IMU